# How to implement type aliases that behave the same but cannot be used together

Tags: scala, types, type-alias

I want to implement two type aliases that "refer" to the same underlying type (so they behave the same, have the same methods) but cannot be mixed together.

Here is the code example :

```
object example {
    case class foo(value: Double):
        def +(that: foo): foo = foo(value + that.value)

    opaque type myType1 <: foo = foo
    opaque type myType2 <: foo = foo

    extension (d: Double)
      def toMyType1: myType1 = new myType1(d)
      def toMyType2: myType2 = new myType2(d)
}


import example.{myType1, myType2}
import example.{toMyType1, toMyType2}

val a1 = 1.5.toMyType1 //a1: myType1
val a2 = 2.4.toMyType1 //a2: myType1
val b1 = 3.2.toMyType2 //b1: myType2

val a3 = a1 + a2       //a3: foo      but wanted      a3: myType1

val c1 = a1 + b1       //c1: foo      but wanted      COMPILATION ERROR (can't add "myType1" and "myType2")
```

Wanted behaviour :

- two values of `myType1` can be added together, resulting in a new `myType1` (same for `myType2`)
- values of `myType1` and `myType2` cannot be added together (compilation error)

Idea behind this: you can't add meters and seconds together, even though adding meters with meters or seconds with seconds work the same.

For the record: I thought that using `opaque` for the type aliases would make the compiler treat `myType1`and `myType2`as two different types (forbidding addition between them), even though they are effectively the same type.

Comment: I believe you need to have your opaque type not extending `foo`. But then probably it means you need to redefine operation `+` multiple times for each opaque type.

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes I thought of this solution but it just seems "suboptimal" since I specifically created `foo` to describe a similar behaviour for all my type aliases

Comment: This is usually achieved in Scala using type classes rather than common supertype. Especially, if you don't want to mix random subtypes together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use type class. Since you are using Scala 3 you can use improved support for type classes in Scala 3:

```
object example {

  opaque type myType1 = Double
  opaque type myType2 = Double

  extension (d: Double)
    def toMyType1: myType1 = d
    def toMyType2: myType2 = d

  // type class definition
  trait Semigroup[A]:
    extension (a1: A) def +(a2: A): A

  // type class instance
  private val semigroupDouble = new Semigroup[Double]:
    extension (a1: Double) def +(a2: Double): Double = a1 + a2
  given Semigroup[myType1] = semigroupDouble
  given Semigroup[myType2] = semigroupDouble
}

import example.*

val a1 = 1.5.toMyType1 //a1: myType1
val a2 = 2.4.toMyType1 //a2: myType1
val b1 = 3.2.toMyType2 //b1: myType2

a1 + a2 // myType1

//a1 + b1 // compilation error
```

Comment: Could the trait `Semigroup[A]` be used for higher kinded types ? Like `trait Semigroup[A[_]]` ? If so, how could I then instantiate the value ? `val semigroupHigher = new Semigroup[SomeType[SomeOtherType]]` ?

Comment: Theoretically, you could use `A <: AnyKind` and then do some `inline def` with pattern matching on types... but in general it's better to have separate type classes for separate kinds. So I'd recommend instead e.g. `given listSemigroup[A]: Semigroup[List[A]] = ...`. Alternatively, use Cats approach: separate `trait SemigroupK[F[_]]` which combines 2 `F[A]` in dedicated method (let's say `++`)  taking `[A]` type parameter or providing `given fromSemigroupK[F[_], A](using SemigroupK[F]): Semigroup[F[A]]`.  It's easier to grasp and work with in practice.