# How to Auto Generate Commutative Instances of a Type Class in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm having some fun exploring Scala's type system and I've come across an interesting challenge inspired by Scala 3's [Multiversal Equality](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html). I'm working on a program where I have a type class representing a commutative operation. I want to automatically generate instances of this type class with swapped parameters, so that if I have an instance for `(T1, T2)`, I automatically get an instance for `(T2, T1)`.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```scala
package typst.tpredef

trait CommutativeAdd[-T1 <: TAny, -T2 <: TAny, +Out <: TAny]:
  def add(t1: T1, t2: T2): Out

object CommutativeAdd:
  def apply[T1 <: TAny, T2 <: TAny, Out <: TAny](using
      instance: CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out],
  ): CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out] = instance

given canAddTNoneTAny[T <: TAny]: CommutativeAdd[TNone, T, T] with {
  def add(t1: TNone, t2: T): T = t2
}

given canAddTAnyTNone[T <: TAny]: CommutativeAdd[T, TNone, T] with {
  def add(t1: T, t2: TNone): T = t1
}

extension [T1 <: TAny, T2 <: TAny, Out <: TAny](
    t1: T1
)(using canAdd: CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out])
  @targetName("add")
  inline infix def +(t2: T2): Out = canAdd.add(t1, t2)

val a = TInteger(1) + tNone
val b = tNone + TInteger(1) // <- errors out here
```

I'm not sure how long Scastie keeps files up, but here's the gist of it, scroll to the bottom. Any feedback on the other parts are more than welcome. [Link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RJ8lRi2BT52xafDn3K9QFg).

---

###### Error

```
value + is not a member of typst.tpredef.TNone.

An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:

typst.tpredef.+[typst.tpredef.TNone, T2, Out](typst.tpredef.tNone)(
  /* ambiguous: both given instance canAddTNoneTAny in package typst.tpredef and given instance canAddAnyTNone in package typst.tpredef match type typst.tpredef.CommutativeAdd[typst.tpredef.TNone, T2, Out] */
  summon[typst.tpredef.CommutativeAdd[typst.tpredef.TNone, T2, Out]]
)

failed with:

Ambiguous given instances: both given instance canAddTNoneTAny in package typst.tpredef and given instance canAddAnyTNone in package typst.tpredef match type typst.tpredef.CommutativeAdd[typst.tpredef.TNone, T2, Out] of parameter canAdd of method + in package typst.tpredef
```

---

###### What I've tried:

I've tried several approaches to solve this problem:

- Manually Swapping Parameters: I initially defined a second given instance with the type parameters swapped. This works, but it requires duplicating the code for each operation, which is not ideal.
- Using a Swap Method: I tried to automate the process of swapping parameters by introducing a swap method in the `CommutativeAdd` object. This method takes an instance of `CommutativeAdd[T2, T1, Out]` and returns an instance of `CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out]`. However, this approach still requires manually creating a given instance using `CommutativeAdd.swap`.
- Using Tuples: I explored using tuples to represent the parameters of the add method. This allows me to define instances for both `(TNone, T)` and `(T, TNone)`, but it doesn't provide true commutativity at the type level for my purposes.
- Using Union Types: I discussed the possibility of using union types to represent the parameters of the add method. However, union types don't inherently provide commutativity at the type level, and this approach wouldn't automatically generate instances with swapped parameters.

---

###### Further Details

In my program, I have types like `TAny`, `TNone`, `tNone`, and `TInteger` representing different kinds of values. I can perform operations like addition on these types using the `CommutativeAdd` type class. For example, `TInteger(1) + tNone` and `tNone + TInteger(1)` are equivalent due to the commutativity defined in `CommutativeAdd`. By the way `TNone` is like `Unit`, `tNone` is like `()`, `TInteger` is a boxed `Int`, and `TAny` is a union of `TNone`, `TInteger`, and a couple more types.

---

This is purely for fun and learning, so I'm open to creative and out-of-the-box solutions. Is there a way to achieve this in Scala? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See `given swapped` in line 120: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/M4p0DkpzQlOFZDYn4WqwJA ( commenting on the phone so can't post a proper reply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to automatically generate instances of this type class with
> swapped parameters, so that if I have an instance for `(T1, T2)`, I
> automatically get an instance for `(T2, T1)`.

This can be achieved with a parameterized `given` instance:

```
given [T1 <: TAny, T2 <: TAny, Out <: TAny](using canAdd: CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out]): CommutativeAdd[T2, T1, Out] with {
  def add(t2: T2, t1: T1): Out = canAdd.add(t1, t2)
}
```

**Note**: one of your two `given` instances (`canAddTAnyTNone` and `canAddTNoneTAny`) can therefore be deleted.

**BUT** this is not the source of your issue. Your issue comes from your `extension` method and the way you handle type parameters. Here is a revised version (pay attention to the type parameters):

```
extension [T1 <: TAny](t1: T1)
  def +[T2 <: TAny, Out <: TAny](t2: T2)(using canAdd: CommutativeAdd[T1, T2, Out]): Out = canAdd.add(t1, t2)
```

**Going further:** your approach is right but a little bit verbose. You could try to find a way to "group" certain operation that are very similar (for example, `TInteger` and `TFloat` behave exactly the same, they just have different types).

> I'm having some fun exploring Scala's type system

Finally, you could try to complete your challenge by leveraging Scala's type system even more using **opaque type** for example. [Here is a lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75776089/how-to-implement-type-aliases-that-behave-the-same-but-cannot-be-used-together)

Comment: Ah wow! So you can create `given`s from `using`s. I don't understand how the extension doesn't brake just from passing the `using` to the method instead of putting it as a second parameter list of the value we are extending (like I did). I was trying the opaque types thing by myself but it got too complicated and I cared more about this part. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: See it this way: if you put the second parameter list (hence all 3 type parameters) on the extension (rather than on the following method declaration), this means that all the parameters (types and implicit parameters) must be resolved for any `t1` of type `T1` without knowing what (and if a) method will be used. That doesn't make sense, you first have to know the type on which you are calling the method from (`T1`), then know which method (`+`) and then the method parameters and types (`T2`). Hope that helps.